# Android App Publishing

Tags: android, publish

I am closing my app programatically on a button click. If anyone can suggest this is ok with google's android app publishing guidelines. I am concerned if it gets rejected because of this. Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rejected? Nope... Google Play Store is nothing like the Apple App Store. As long as you're not publishing a malicious app, Google doesn't care what your app's functionality is.


My suggestion is to remove the button anyway to better comply with Android standards. Your users are expecting to exit your app by pressing the home button.

Answer (score 0):

**Nahh..** There isn't any problem of closing app programatically.

But as suggested in "Android docs" You have to manage your app flow in a way that you don't need to Close your app programatically.

Then even you want to do it then you are the boss of your app.